# How to display multiple images inside tkinter window?

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I want to display 7 different images and plot them inside tkinter window. I only know to display it using OpenCV which actually displays the image outside the Tkinter GUI window. How to plot the images inside the GUI window?

Tkinter GUI:

[image]

Comment: Your first step should be to work through a tkinter tutorial or read some documentation. There are countless examples on the internet of displaying images witk tkinter.

Comment: I didn't get solution yet. Would be really helpful if someone help me as i'm starting from scratch. I have attached image of my window.

Comment: I just gotta need the images to be plotted inside the window whenever I press each button. totally I have 7 buttons, so want those 7 images to be plotted. If I google it only shows how to display a single image.

Comment: Start by creating a blank window. Try to add one image. There are plenty of examples in the internet. Next, add a second. If you get stuck, show what you've tried. Stackoverflow isn't intended to be a tutorial site.

Answer (score 1):

I advise you read the documentation of tkinter as it has tons of example on how to achieve a soluction to your problem. I have made a sample GUI which updates image on the GUI with a randomized pixel picture. Note that there are a lot of different approaches how to do this. In my case I have made a class in which I display a frame and a button. The button calls a function to randomize the image (or changes to the next one in your case) and calls the function to update the frame with a new image. Hope it gives you a jump start. Cheers!

P.S.: for multiple images use more labels and functions;)

Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


class DisplayImage:

    def __init__(self, master):        
        self.master = master
        master.title("GUI")
        self.image_frame = Frame(master, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, height=20, width=30, bg='white')
        self.image_frame.pack()
        self.image_label = Label(self.image_frame, highlightthickness=0, borderwidth=0)
        self.image_label.pack()
        self.Next_image = Button(master, command=self.read_image, text="Next image", width=17, default=ACTIVE, borderwidth=0)
        self.Next_image.pack()

    def display_image(self, event=None):
        self.cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(self.img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
        self.from_array = Image.fromarray(self.cv2image)
        self.imgt = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=self.from_array)
        self.image_label.configure(image=self.imgt)

    def read_image(self, event=None):
        self.img = np.random.randint(255, size=(250,250,3),dtype=np.uint8)
        self.master.after(10, self.display_image)     


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    GUI = DisplayImage(root)
    GUI.read_image()
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are OK with using a wrapper with tkinter, then [PySimpleGUI](http://www.PySimpleGUI.org) is a good choice.

There was a new Demo application posted this week that demonstrates how to show a webcam in a GUI window.  There's another Demo posted that plays back a video file using OpenCV, again in a GUI window.

[image]

The code that generated that screen shot can be found here:
[Open and Play Video Using PySimpleGU + OpenCV](https://github.com/MikeTheWatchGuy/PySimpleGUI/blob/master/Demo_OpenCV.py)

You can start with the Demo and expand it by adding more buttons.